# How can I transfer the values of a grid of smaller polygons to another grid with larger polygons in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, overlapping-features, density, population

I have a population density grid containing 100x100m polygons. I would like to transfer the density values into an existing overlaying grid of larger polygons (250x250m). This might of course include modifications of the actual values.

any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed 100*100m polygons borders are not match with the larger polygons (See the below image).

[image]

So, you can use [Intersect](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) tool. After that, summarize population density for each grid in larger polygons.

1. Open **Intersect** tool. Select two Feature classes (larger and smaller polygon fc).

   - Set an output feature class.
   - "Join Attribute"= "All" .
   - "Output Type" = "Input".
2. Open attribute table of the intersect output and Select **FID** field of larger polygon layer (There are two FID fields in output layer.Each for the two polygon layers).
3. Right click heading of this field and click [Summarize](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/summarizing-data-in-a-table.htm).
4. In the summarize window For "population density" field, Select "Sum".
5. Join result of summarize with larger polygon layer (Join based on ID's)

Comment: @Sebastian. If my answer answered your question could you accept this answer with the checkbox if my answer answered your question? It can help others to trust answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer wetland! Very helpful, but it does not solve my issue completely since the sum of all smaller polygons would turn out in a much too high density value for the larger polygon. Instead of "Sum" I calculated the average value for each larger polygon which I then multiplied by the factor of the surface difference. this still does not provide the exact density for each polygon but should be quite close top it.